# Laravel Form Submit receives undefined

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

**EDIT:**
*I just found out, that the error is generated from my jquery.mobile-1.1.2.min.js. 
I don't know why and I don't know how to fix it yet, but I thought, that I just should you guys know.*

For some reason, I can't submit. Please help.

These are my routes:

```
    Route::get('forms/{unit_id}/{qr_id}', 'FormController@index');
Route::resource('units.qr.score', 'ScoreController');
```

And these are my Controller:

FormController:

```
public function index($unit_id, $qr_id)
{
    //
    return View::make('form.index')
        ->with('unit_id', $unit_id)
        ->with('qr_id', $qr_id);
}
```

ScoreController:

```
public function index()
{
    //
    return '<h1>Yeeeeeas?!</h1>';
}


    **// EDIT: Changed show to store**
public function store($unit_id, $qr_id)
{
    //
    return $unit_id;
}
```

And this is my View:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.2/jquery.mobile-1.1.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.2/jquery.mobile-1.1.2.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Title rockt</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>Hello world</p>  
        {{Form::open(array('route' => array('units.qr.score.store', $unit_id, $qr_id)))}}

            {{Form::label('rating1')}}
            {{Form::input('range', 'rating1', 50, array('min' => '0', 'max' => '100', 'data-highlight' => 'true', 'id' => 'rating1', 'placeholder' => 'What the fuck?'))}}

            {{Form::label('Test1')}}
            {{Form::text('Test1')}}

            {{Form::submit('Submit')}}

        {{Form::close()}}   

    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

So, I don't know why when I push the Submit button, I just get the message "undefined".
If I reload it returns the correct value from my ScoreController.

Here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6KIH.png

And help would be appreciated.

Thx and much Love,

George

Comment: erm.... that is not laravel's error page.

Comment: I know.... sadly... but I get the same behaviour, if I remove all the javascript.

Comment: What is in your store method? This looks to me like you're printing a variable and followed by a manual `die()`.

Comment: I updated the store method, because I accidentally had the variables in the show method. But the problem ist still not resolved.

Comment: I nailed the mistake down to the jquery.mobile-1.1.2.min.js. Whenever it is commented out, the can transmit witout errors,

When it is not commented out, I get the above mentioned screenshot. Isn't this weird?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You are having an issue with jQuery Mobile.

You need to return a complete jQuery Mobile page.

Related questions:

- [JQuery Mobile - changePage result: undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067528/jquery-mobile-changepage-result-undefined)
- [Why am I seeing a
  value of “undefined” on screen when I submit form in jQuery
  Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787461/why-am-i-seeing-a-value-of-undefined-on-screen-when-i-submit-form-in-jquery-mo)

Comment: You mean instead of using the parameters in the URL, right?

Comment: I made the changements. Still no difference to the error.

Comment: Then I don't think it's a problem with laravel. What does chrome (or firefox, or whatever you use) dev tools show the form tag attributes as?

Comment: @LoveAndHappiness Nevermind. It is a jquery mobile issue. See edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for these links. I haven't yet solve the problem, but I believe your answer brought me nearer to it. I will update this post if I get the question right.

Comment: I solved the problem. I had to add a 'data-ajax="false"' to every link. Now it works, for everyone else reading this, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Store shouldn't have parameters. Use Input::get('unit_id','unit id empty'); It's Posted.

Edit:
And put the unit id etc as hidden inputs..

Answer (score 0):

In accordance to what decker wrote correctly, the solution is to insert the following parameter to every link and submit button:

```
 data-ajax="false"
```

Like this:

```
 {{Form::open(array('url' => 'whatever', 'method' => 'POST', 'data-ajax' => 'false'))}}
```

Or like this:

```
 {{link_to('whatever', 'whatever', array('data-ajax' => 'false'))}}
```

Here another resource:

[jQuery Mobile links not working without data-ajax="false", why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533359/jquery-mobile-links-not-working-without-data-ajax-false-why)

Comment: Good job! Congrats on figuring it out. Feels good until the next hurdle ;)